# How to set shell-mode prompt in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have set in my ~/.emacs.d/init_bash.sh:

```
export PS1='\h:\w$ '
```

without it, my prompt is

```
bash-3.2$
```

but now it is

```
bash-3.2$ computername:~/path/to/directory$
```

How do I make it just be

```
computername:~/path/to/directory$
```

?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to just do this on the first line in the Emacs shell, and "bash-3.2$" goes away after I hit return once.  To really get rid of "bash-3.2$", set PS1 in your ~/.bashrc instead.